# DNS, domain, firewall issue on port 8090

Tags: domain, hostname, jira, confluence

I have a server running Jira and Confluence.

Jira @ http://jira.domain.com:**8080**
Confluence @ http://wiki.domain.com:**8090**

I can reach the applications from the **server**, from my **home pc**. But on my **work pc** only Jira is accessible. **What am I missing??**

## On the server:

**Jira:**

```
http://jira.domain.com:8080 WORKS
http://localhost:8080 WORKS
```

**Confluence:**

```
http://wiki.domain.com:8090 WORKS
http://localhost:8090 WORKS
```

## Home PC:

**Jira:**

```
http://jira.domain.com:8080 WORKS
```

**Confluence**

```
http://wiki.domain.com:8090 WORKS
```

## Work PC:

**Jira:**

```
http://jira.domain.com:8080 WORKS
```

**Confluence**

```
http://wiki.domain.com:8090  !!!! DOES NOT WORK !!!!
```

Comment: What do you mean by does not work - what error messages do you get ?

Comment: It doesn't resolve the host name to ip. Default Chrome error message: "Cannot connect to wiki.domain.com:8090"

Comment: Maybe a proxy on your work PC. Could be an automatically detected proxy.

Comment: 8090 is the port I use for websockets. Took me a long time to realise that it's generally blocked at various network points. I had to proxy my link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like an ACL somewhere. Most likely a firewall rule or restriction in .htaccess or similar.

Comment: I thought firewall also, however it's not on the server side (home pc works) and my work pc has port 8090 allowed as inbound port...

Comment: Your work PC's firewall doesn't factor in there. The return traffic wouldn't be on 8090. There's probably a hardware firewall in place somewhere that is blocking the traffic.

Answer (score 2):

You don't give any information about the network topology `work-->server<--home` but they are unlikely to take the same route so make absolutely sure that there isn't some device between work and the server that is blocking port.

If it's not a firewall blocking the route to the port then check that the hostname is resolving correctly from your work PC use

```
dig  wiki.domain.com   (linux)
```

or

```
nslookup wiki.domain.com   (windows)
```

If the DNS is OK then I'm out other than to check your hosts file.

Comment: Resolving works fine. It is the port that is blocked by our company. Thanks.